# Unit test computed property on an Ember controller

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit

The code from my **controllers/cart.js**:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  cartTotal: Ember.computed('model.@each.subTotal', function() {
    return this.model.reduce(function(subTotal, product) {
      var total = subTotal + product.get('subTotal');
      return total;
    }, 0);
  })
)};
```

This computed property loops over all the elements in the model, adding all the values of the `subTotal` property, returning a `cart total`.

**cart-test.js**

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';

moduleFor('controller:cart', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  // needs: ['controller:foo']
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var controller = this.subject();
  assert.ok(controller);
});

test('cartTotal function exists', function(assert) {
  var controller = this.subject();
  assert.equal(controller.get('cartTotal'), 30, 'The cart total function exists');
});
```

The test fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null` because it obviously doesn't have a model to loop over.

How can I mock the dependencies of the `cartTotal` computed property to make the test pass?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the rest of your test's code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines maybe?

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

import Ember from 'ember';

var products = [
  Ember.Object.create({ name: 'shoe', subTotal: 10 }), 
  Ember.Object.create({ name: 'shirt', subTotal: 20 })];

var model = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: Ember.A(products)
});

moduleFor('controller:cart', {
  beforeEach() {
    this.controller = this.subject();
  }
});

test('cartTotal', function(assert) {
  this.controller.set('model', model);
  assert.equal(this.controller.get('cartTotal'), 30, 'The cart total function exists');
});
```

Comment: yes! With a little difference: instead of `Product.create` we could not even import our model and instead use `Ember.Object.create`

In fact with the `Product.create` I got errors. It worked with Ember.Object.create. 

If you make the changes to your answer I shall mark it as the correct one.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I just pulled examples from different sources and don't have an actual ember-cli app to test stuff in so I don't know why importing the model doesn't work. Oh well.

Comment: it was importing. it failed with an error to use `store.createRecord` instead of `Product.create`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this would be to stub the model in the `beforeEach` hook:

```
var sampleModel = [ // sample data that follows your actual model structure ]

moduleFor('controller:cart', {
  beforeEach() {
    this.controller = this.subject(); // allows you to access it in the tests without having to redefine it each time
    this.controller.set('model', sampleModel);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my first post with the result I got from trying this out. I have a feeling I may not be doing it correctly, but I feel like I got closer.

Comment: Your answer was going down the right path though :)

Comment: Oups, used an object instead of an array x.x